# Javascript filter and match all elements in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like:

```
var testArr = ["40", "A1", "B9", "58"]
```

I want to loop over all div elements of a certain class and return only the elements where the data attribute matches ANY of the items in that array.

If I do something like this:

```
$("div.prodCodes").filter(function(e) {
    var x1 = $(this);
    var x2 =  $(this).data("prodCode");

    testArr.forEach(function(e) { if (e == x2) {  console.log("MATCH"); } });
});
```

That console outputs the correct number of matches, but I cannot *return* those elements from the filter function.

What on earth am I missing here? I've tried creating a new array and pushing each item onto it and returning *that*, but it's always empty. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. I've also tried rewriting this using .grep() and getting nowhere. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Set` for constant-time lookup.

Be aware that jQuery reads the attribute value "58" as a number when using the `data` method, so it won't match unless you make sure the data type is the same:

```js
// Use a set
var testSet = new Set(["40", "A1", "B9", "58"]);

var texts = $("div.prodCodes").filter(function() {
    var x = $(this).data("prodCode").toString(); // data type must match
    // Return a boolean to indicate whether the div element should be kept
    return testSet.has(x); // Set#has() is fast
}).map(function(){
    // For demo only: get the text content of the matching div elements
    return $(this).text();
}).get(); // convert that to a plain array

console.log(texts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prodCodes" data-prod-code="A1">Hello</div>
<div class="prodCodes" data-prod-code="XX">Not this one</div>
<div class="prodCodes" data-prod-code="58">There</div>
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? As far as I can see it does the job in the snippet and highlights the data type mismatch problem. Could someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: I did not downvote you, someone else did. This is overkill for what I need, but you solved my problem. I have a datatype mismatch, and the toString() conversion fixes my issue.

Comment: True, I added some extra code to show the results, as texts display better than whole `div` nodes. I added the `Set` idea, as it leads to *O(n)*  time complexity instead of *O(nm)*, where *n* is the number of `div` elements, and *m* the size of the test array. For small data that is indeed overkill, but it does not hurt, and does not make your code larger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a truthy value in `filter()` to have an item included.

Try :

```
$("div.prodCodes").filter(function(e) {
    return testArr.indexOf($(this).attr('data-prodCode')) >-1;
}).doSomething();
```

Without a `return` all items will be excluded

Comment: Doing it that way only matches on the FIRST element in testArr. So I should be getting 60 items back, this only matches any that are "40", which in my dataset is 5 items.

Comment: datatype mismatch. If I say $(this).data("prodCode").toString(), it works correctly. I had your exact solution an hour ago and couldn't figure out why it was only returning the first element.

Comment: If you use `attr` you have to specify the argument with hashes instead of Camel case: `data-prod-code`. `data()` may be more efficient if you use the code repeatedly and don't change the attribute dynamically later, as `data()` only reads out the attribute value once which then lives its own life in memory.

Comment: Yes, if you define the HTML like that, but note that this wont work with the OP's code, which clearly has `data-prod-code` as attribute name, otherwise the `data('prodCode')` method call would [not work](https://jsfiddle.net/hb9hnzrg/).

Comment: @trincot ah right...forgot that data() has camelCase vs hash convention

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elements = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

const objects = [
  { id: 1, fruit: 'apple' },

  { id: 2, fruit: 'pear' },

  { id: 3, fruit: 'orange' },

  { id: 4, fruit: 'banana' }
];

const results = objects.filter(obj => elements.includes(obj.fruit));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).